# I can not pass the header

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
    angular.module("suiteESCWeb", ["ngMessages"]);
    angular.module("suiteESCWeb").controller("usuarioCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.app = "Lista Telefonica";

        $scope.usuario = [];

           var config = {headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
            }
        };

        var carregarUsuario = function () {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8080/usuario/1", config).success(function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                $scope.usuario = data;
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
            });
        };

        carregarUsuario();
    });
</script>
```

I am beginning to study AngularJS, part of Back-End is working perfectly the URL tested by postman on chrome now to trying to integrate, trying to make this simple call and never seems to pass the header.

Mistake I always have is:

```
{"timestamp":1473905412331,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'null' not supported","path":"/usuario/1"}

public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Content-Type");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        $http({
            method: "GET", 
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/usuario/1',
            headers: config
        }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {          
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {                
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but to no avail, he does not pass the header when I debug google chrome.

Comment: `Request URL:http://localhost:8080/usuario/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:415 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 15 Sep 2016 02:43:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked`

Comment: Check with fiddler

Comment: Here on the General tab was to have a Content-Type application / json sure if it had worked?

Comment: Yes, thats the way, the config you showed here should be applied on the server side to avoid cors

Comment: `The error points to the line: AngularJS: 12011 GET http: //localhost:8080/ usuario/1 415 ()`

Comment: I set up the back-end for this look up I includes. CORSFilter